# How can I turn a field into a link?

Tags: 7, views, entities

I've got a content type with fields whose values are URLs. I'd like to use a view to display these as links, using the field label as link name, something like `<a href="{field_value}">{field_label}</a>`.

I've got the field values displaying correctly. I just can't figure out how to turn them into links like above (or if this is even possible).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use REWRITE RESULTS with REPLACEMENT PATTERNS

```
<a href="[field_value]">Any Text</a>
```

**Example**
If i want to edit any node

```
<a href="node/[nid]/edit">Any Text</a>
```

Comment: [field_value] is okay but I am not sure if Views can get [field_label] for you like this

Answer (score 0):

use [hook_views_pre_render()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7.x-3.x)

```
MYMODULE_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == '<Your-view-name>') {
    foreach($view->result as $key => $row) {
      // change field values to href, or whatever for every row
    }
  }
}
```

OR, if this looks too complex and cumbersome, you can go for template preprocess for one of the templates under **Theme information** in Views UI.